# Getting the current record id

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm working on suppliers form view (res.partner model). 
 i've tried to have the current record's id by the code below:

```
current_id=fields.Integer(compute='get_current_id')
@api.multi
def get_current_id(self):
    print self.id
    self.current_id=self.id
```

with this code, i have the error : "ValueError: Expected singleton: res.partner(1, 50)" which is weird because 50 is my current record id but i don't know why it's getting the id 1 also. When i've looked for it in pgAdmin, i found out that 1 is the "company_id". Why the current record (view form)  is having two ids?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough context to grasp why you're confused: it seems that in this domain, "company #1, partner record #50" is a reasonable way to identify the record.  I can't investigate, because you've failed to provide the suggested [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  If all of this is directly implied by the `odoo` context, I'll leave the solution to others more familiar with it; if not, you need to make this easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@api.multi`, so `self` can be more than one record.

You can try:

```
@api.multi
def get_current_id(self):
    for instance in self:
        instance.current_id = instance.id
```

Or:

```
@api.one
def get_current_id(self):
    self.current_id = self.id
```

Comment: When i've tried this, with a  "print" , it gives me two ids which are 1 and 50 (two iterations) , even if i'm in the form view of the supplier which has the id "50". I don't know why i get the id 1 too!